# Tax query is not working!

Tags: wp-query

```
    $

        $arg =  array(
            'post_type' => 'plusnagarmitra',
            'posts_per_page' => '10',


            'tax_query' => array(array(
                'taxonomy' => category,

                'terms' => 14

              ) ),

            'post_status' => array(
                'publish',
                'pending',
                'draft',
                'private',

            )
        ) ;

        $loop = new WP_QUERY($arg);
            ?>
        <div id="users">
                          <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
                          <button class="sort" data-sort="name">
                            Sort by name
                          </button>
                           <button class="sort" data-sort="mobile">
                            Sort by Mobile
                          </button>

            <table id="postTable" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
               <th>Name</th><th>ID</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Address</th><th>SEX</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

<tbody class="list">
            <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>



        <tr>
            <td class="name"><?php the_title( '<p class="entry-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></p>' ); ?></td>



            <td class"ID"><?php echo get_field('nm_id'); ?></td>



            <td class="mobile"><?php echo  get_field('durbash_mobile_no'); ?></td>


            <td class="address"><?php echo  get_field('stayi_pata'); ?></td>



            <td class="sex"><?php echo  get_field('ling'); ?></td>

            <td><?php echo get_post_status( get_the_ID() ) ?></td>

            <td class="sex"> <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">✍ EDIT</a> </td>



        </tr>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
            </tbody>

        </table>
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around `category` as the taxonomy in your query:

```
'taxonomy' => category,
```

Needs to be

```
'taxonomy' => 'category',
```

So the taxonomy query looks this

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms'    => 14
    )
),
```

Comment: $loop = new WP_Query( array(
   
   
       'post_type' => 'plusnagarmitra',
       'posts_per_page' => '-1',
       
       
       'post_status' => array(
           'publish',
           'pending',
           'draft',
           'private',
           
       ),
       
     'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms'    => 21
    )
)
   ) );

Comment: Thank you soo much for replying But It is still not working

Comment: What’s not working. Getting no posts or the wrong posts? The taxonomy query I posted is correct, so either you’re using the wrong term or taxonomy name, or something else about the query is wrong.

Comment: if you put  `"terms" => 14`  it is evaluated as an interger. If it  a string it should be `"terms"=>"14"`

Comment: Term ids are integers.